# Multi loops in PHP language

Tags: php, foreach

I have three loops of values which confuse me how to show the correct output.

First I have a sentence for instance this:

> Back in 1951 , the astronomer , Gerard P . Kuiper , was pondering the
>   crowns , especially those that loop around the Sun in less than 200
>   years . These comets include Halley's Comet - last seen from earth in
>   1985/86 - and Shoemaker-Levy which crashed into Jupiter in 1994 . He
>   worked out that comets like these would have to come from a belt
>   fairly close to the planets of the solar system . He noticed that
>   these comments also tend to come hurting in from outer space quite
>   close to the plane of the planets , rather than from just any old
>   direction . Kuiper predicted that there should be a flattened belt or
>   frisk of comets and asteroids , beginning just outside the orbit of
>   Neptune 30 AU and reaching out to about 1,000 AU or astronomical units
>   . But finding a comet past Neptune , is like trying to see a 100-watt
>   light bulb at 20 times the distance of the Moon . Well , back in 1992
>   , our television technology finally got good enough .

Now I marked some of the keywords in my database table as following :

```
crowns,that,comments,frisk,finding
```

And I will have some answers from the user side :

```
was,that,comments,see,finding
```

Now I need to show if the user marked the correct values inside the text, so first I tried to use a foreach loop and in array function, but the problem is with the duplicated keywords such as *that*.

**How can I fix the problem of showing user answers and check if his/her answer is correct compared to the marked keywords.**

```
$text_array =  preg_split("/(\w\S+\w)|(\w+)|(\s*\.{3}\s*)|(\s*[^\w\s]\s*)|\s+/", $object->text,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) ;
$answvals=[]; $answvals = explode(',',  $object->answer->answer);
$marked_keys = explode(',', $object->marked_keys);


        <p class="card-text">

            @foreach($text_array as $val)

            <span class="
             @if( $object->answer != null )
                      @if(in_array($val,$answvals))
                           @if(in_array($val,$marked_keys))
                    bg-success
                         @else
                       bg-danger
                         @endif
                  @endif

            @endif
            ">
            {{str_replace(' ', '', $val)}} </span>
        @endforeach
        </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the key to my question is reverse thinking. The problem was duplicate keywords and when using in_array function in PHP it wanted to check all keywords inside the array. Then I thought what if I remove the found keywords from the array so it would not check again.

I think the right solution is adding bellow code inside the foreach loop after checking if the val is equal to the answer:

```
            $index = array_search($val,$answvals);
              if($index !== FALSE){
                  unset($answvals[$index]);
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a function that you can use to find the array of duplicate word and keys, and use that to show duplicates in your loop, if the key matches in any of the sub array it's a duplicate.

```
$sentence = "Back in 1951 , the astronomer , Gerard P . Kuiper , was pondering the crowns , especially those that loop around the Sun in less than 200 years . These comets include Halley's Comet - last seen from earth in 1985/86 - and Shoemaker-Levy which crashed into Jupiter in 1994 . He worked out that comets like these would have to come from a belt fairly close to the planets of the solar system . He noticed that these comments also tend to come hurting in from outer space quite close to the plane of the planets , rather than from just any old direction . Kuiper predicted that there should be a flattened belt or frisk of comets and asteroids , beginning just outside the orbit of Neptune 30 AU and reaching out to about 1,000 AU or astronomical units . But finding a comet past Neptune , is like trying to see a 100-watt light bulb at 20 times the distance of the Moon . Well , back in 1992 , our television technology finally got good enough .";

$marked = explode(',', 'crowns,that,comments,frisk,finding');

$answers = explode(',', 'was,that,comments,see,finding');

$words =  preg_split("/(\w\S+\w)|(\w+)|(\s*\.{3}\s*)|(\s*[^\w\s]\s*)|\s+/", $sentence,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) ;

function find_duplicate_word_keys($words, $answers, $marked){
    $search_words = $answers;
    $duplicate_word_keys = [];
    foreach($search_words as $search_word){

        if(in_array($search_word, $marked)){
            foreach($words as $key=>$word){
                if($search_word == $word){
                    $duplicate_word_keys[$search_word][] = $key;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return $duplicate_word_keys;
}

$duplicate_word_keys = find_duplicate_word_keys($words, $answers, $marked);

print_r($duplicate_word_keys);
```

here is a working [link](https://tehplayground.com/RfsiqfXTvTHDIY97), hope it helps.

**Edit: New Code**

Please try it.

```
$sentence = "Back in 1951 , the astronomer , Gerard P . Kuiper , was pondering the crowns , especially those that loop around the Sun in less than 200 years . These comets include Halley's Comet - last seen from earth in 1985/86 - and Shoemaker-Levy which crashed into Jupiter in 1994 . He worked out that comets like these would have to come from a belt fairly close to the planets of the solar system . He noticed that these comments also tend to come hurting in from outer space quite close to the plane of the planets , rather than from just any old direction . Kuiper predicted that there should be a flattened belt or frisk of comets and asteroids , beginning just outside the orbit of Neptune 30 AU and reaching out to about 1,000 AU or astronomical units . But finding a comet past Neptune , is like trying to see a 100-watt light bulb at 20 times the distance of the Moon . Well , back in 1992 , our television technology finally got good enough .";

$marked = explode(',', 'crowns,that,comments,frisk,finding');

$answers = explode(',', 'was,that,comments,see,finding');

$words =  preg_split("/(\w\S+\w)|(\w+)|(\s*\.{3}\s*)|(\s*[^\w\s]\s*)|\s+/", $sentence,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) ;

function find_duplicate_word_keys($words, $answers, $marked){
    $search_words = $answers;
    $duplicate_word_keys = [];
    foreach($search_words as $search_word){

        if(in_array($search_word, $marked)){
            foreach($words as $key=>$word){
                if($search_word == $word){
                    $duplicate_word_keys[$search_word][] = $key;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return $duplicate_word_keys;
}

$duplicate_word_keys = find_duplicate_word_keys($words, $answers, $marked);

// print_r($duplicate_word_keys);

$answer_keys = array_keys($duplicate_word_keys);

echo '<p>';

foreach($words as $key=>$w){

    if(in_array($w, $answer_keys)){
        if(in_array($key, $duplicate_word_keys[$w])){

            echo "<span style='color:green;'>$w</span> ";
        }
    }else{

        if(in_array($w, $answers) && !in_array($w, $marked)){

            echo "<span style='color:red;'>$w</span> ";
        }else{
            echo "$w ";
        }
    }

}

echo '</p>';
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not looking for a function to find the duplicate keys , I am looking for a way to mark user answers and check if his answer is correct with compare to the marked keywords I have.

Comment: @MacTaylor i edited my answer, please see if it works.

Comment: I think you must remove the used ones otherwise it will check it again. Just consider we have keywords like "that" and only the first one is marked.

Comment: I like that actually, it's a brilliant approach. 
but can you please have a look at this [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/2UikjB.jpg), I just want to know if my solution works or not. Thank you. I'm still learning.